# Cannot maintain a PHP session in JSoup

Tags: java, php, cookies, jsoup, session-cookies

I'm trying to retrieve information from a catalog using JSoup, it always has 9 columns per row, the 6th column specifically is a placeholder for when you are logged in, when you actually are logged in to the site, that column shows "price".

I have the following: (username and password not shown here)

```
    Document doc = null;
    String url;

    Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.prisa.cl/home/?page=iniciaSesion")
        .method(Method.GET)
        .timeout(10000)
        .execute();       

    String sessionID = res.cookie("PHPSESSID");
    System.out.println(sessionID);

    res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.prisa.cl/home/?page=iniciaSesion")
        .data("email_address", username, "password", password)
        .method(Method.POST)
        .timeout(10000)
        .execute();   
    sessionID = res.cookie("PHPSESSID");
    System.out.println(sessionID);



        for(int page=1; page<=1; page++){
            url = "https://www.prisa.cl/catalog/advanced_search_result.php"
                    + "?keywords=%20&enviar=&categories_id=&manufacturers_id=&pfrom=&pto=&sort=2a&&page="+page;
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookie("PHPSESSID", sessionID)
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .get();

            for(Element table : doc.select("table table table table table")){        
                for(Element row : table.select("tr")){ 
                  Elements tds = row.select("td");
                  if(tds.size() == 9){   
                       System.out.println(tds.select("img[src]").attr("src")+";"+
                               tds.get(1).text()+";"+
                               tds.get(2).text()+";"+
                               tds.get(3).text()+";"+
                               tds.get(4).text()+";"+
                               tds.get(5).text()+";"+
                               tds.get(6).text());
                  } //end if
                } //rows                 
            } //tables
            System.out.println("finished page: "+page);
        } //pages
```

what i think/hope is happening here is:

1- I'm getting the PHPSESSID cookie while not logged in (for debugging purposes)

2- I'm getting the PHPSESSID again while logged in (has different data)

3- I'm iterating for each page in the catalog (used only 1 in the code above) and attempting to send the PHPSESSID cookie during the connection to retrieve the data while logged in

4- Looking for a TR that has 9 TDs while being 5 tables deep (the page layout is a little confusing)

I am super new to this but I actually searched for a couple of days some different methods in Stack Overflow and in the JSoup documentation to no avail.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code? You're having trouble dowloading the html you want to parse? Trouble parsing the html?

Comment: trying to retrieve the HTML, but it changes when you're logged in to the website, and that's what i need, i need my code to make it log in and retrieve the data that the page contains when you're logged in that otherwise won't shown when not logged in